# Cordova Ionic v1 App crashes on deep linking with branch.io in IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, branch.io

I am using ionic v1 to build a cordova project. My app runs in android and iOS. But when I try to implement deeplinking using branch, the app is crashing. I am not able to track the console also. Here is the details of my app.

Node : 6.11.2
Cordova : 7.1.0
Ionic : 1.7.16

Plugin list

```
branch-cordova-sdk 2.6.24 "branch-cordova-sdk"
com.googlemaps.ios 2.7.0 "Google Maps SDK for iOS"
cordova-custom-config 2.0.3 "cordova-custom-config"
cordova-plugin-admobpro-firebase 2.29.23 "AdMob Plugin Pro"
cordova-plugin-apprate 1.1.7 "AppRate"
cordova-plugin-camera 4.0.3 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.1.0 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.7 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.1 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-extension 1.5.4 "Cordova Plugin Extension"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 1.7.4 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-file 4.1.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.5.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.11.0 "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-googlemaps 1.4.5 "cordova-googlemaps-plugin"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 2.0.2 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.4 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.2.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 1.0.1 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.1.8 "SocialSharing"
cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.6.2 "Toast"
cordova.plugins.diagnostic 3.1.7 "Diagnostic"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 1.0.9 "Keyboard"
phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 6.0.8 "BarcodeScanner"
phonegap-plugin-push 2.1.2 "PushPlugin"
```

Here is my code :

Config.xml

```
<plugin name="branch-cordova-sdk" spec="^2.5.0" />
<branch-config>
<branch-key value="key_live_XXXXXXXX" />
<uri-scheme value="xxxx" />
        <link-domain value="xxxx.app.link" />
        <ios-team-release value="XXXXXXX" />
    </branch-config>
```

Code :

```
// for development and debugging only
Branch.setDebug(true)

// for GDPR compliance (can be called at anytime)
Branch.disableTracking(true);

// Branch initialization
Branch.initSession().then(function(data) {
  if (data['+clicked_branch_link']) {
    // read deep link data on click
    alert('Deep Link Data: ' + JSON.stringify(data))
  }
})
```

The app is working fine in Android. But in iOS, it is keep on crashing. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. When I tried to debug using xcode, got the error that branch key not found. When I checked, the info.plist file, branch key was not there. I tried removing and adding the plugin again, but still branch key was not appending to info.plist file. Later I added the following line in my config.xml file, which helped to resolve the issue.

```
<config-file mode="replace" parent="branch_app_domain" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
            <string>myApp.app.link</string>
        </config-file>
<config-file mode="replace" parent="branch_key" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
            <string>key_live_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</string>
        </config-file>
```

After adding the above line in config file and build the app once again. Now branch key has been added to info.plist file and app is working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using an older version(v2.6.24) of the Branch Cordova SDK. The latest release is v3.1.0. Can you update the SDK to the latest version and check if you are able to reproduce the crash on iOS?

If you are still able to reproduce the crash, can you please share the symbolicated crash report by writing to support@branch.io?